# Duplicate an array in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to make a little damage calculator for the game Diablo 3 (I know, I know).

Basically the idea is that it has a "before" and "after" array of values that represent items for your character. The "after" array should duplicate the "before" array when that's updated. However, changes to the "after" array should **not** update the "before" array.

Each array then displays a DPS (more of this is better) total, and it shows you the difference between the two. The idea is then it makes for easy comparison of two items when using the in-game auction house.

I have the first bit set up - the "before" array is working great. However I'm at a loss as to how to create the "after" array, and I'm wondering if I've made this a different magnitude of complexity. Should I be using two view models, replicating it in jQuery, or using the mapping plugin? I can't quite find anything that's exactly what I'm after, the UI requirements especially seem a bit of a sticking point

Fiddle of where I'm up to: http://jsfiddle.net/kimadactyl/GuMuY/8/

Comment: Obviously you need two distinct arrays. The `after` array being a copy of `before` (i.e. deep copy). Then you need to define custom Knockout binding for a `before` array which on update will update the `after` array as well. And you're done! P.S. jbabey, definetly not me - I don't care about Diablo 3. :)

Comment: Thanks - what's the correct way to go about a deep copy here, though? The ones I've tried either update both in sync, or haven't worked properly at all.

When you say a custom binding, do you mean writing a class function? I'm not too great with the terminology!

Edit: I found the docs page, thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: When I say "custom binding" I mean this: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html As for a deep copy... in your case it is enough to initialize `new HeroItem(...)` twice per `HeroItem` and add one to `before` and second to `after` lists.

Comment: I think part of the problem is at the moment every class method is written with relation to the self.items array. So even if I duplicate that array, I still need to abstract my functions - or am I overthinking this? Also, using a jQuery DOM selector to run the $.each statements from seems to just make it crash, as currently if I make 2 tables it adds up everything in both columns. Am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that should get you started. I refactored your `HeroItem` to take a config object and an optional linked Hero.

I am assuming for the moment the array is fixed length. I create the `after` array from the items array by mapping it to a new `HeroItem`, using jquery extend to do a deep copy.

When a `link` is passed in the HeroItem will subscribe to changes on it's observables and update one-way only as specified.

```
function HeroItem(config, link) {
    var self = this, prop;
    self.item = config.item;
    self.int = ko.observable(config.int);
    self.ias = ko.observable(config.ias);
    self.critdmg = ko.observable(config.critdmg);
    self.critpc = ko.observable(config.critpc);
    self.min = ko.observable(config.min);
    self.max = ko.observable(config.max);

    if (link) {
        for (prop in link) {
            if (link.hasOwnProperty(prop) && ko.isObservable(link[prop])) {     
                console.log("subscribing " + prop);
                link[prop].subscribe((function(p) {
                    return function (newValue) {
                        console.log("updating " + p+ " to " + newValue);
                        self[p](newValue);
                    }
                })(prop));
            }
        }        
    }
}

self.after = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(self.items(), function(i) {
    return new HeroItem($.extend({}, ko.toJS(i)), i);
}));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/2MNFn/1/

No custom bindings needed, it just uses the subscription capabilities all KO observables have. If you want to extend this to cope with dynamic length arrays simple subscribe to the items array and cleanup the after array accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this. The refactoring is definitely needed. However I'm still struggling with how to get the new column totals. As they're just references, I can't find a way to get Knockout to add up the "after" columns without breaking the subscription. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't worry, I was overthinking this. You got it perfectly even tho I don't completely understand your extension to the HeroItem object. Thanks!